# Trim last character from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to cut off the last character from a long list of characters.  I create my list like this:

```
r = re.findall(re.escape(start) + "(.+?)" + re.escape(end), html_page, re.DOTALL)
```

The regex and everything works fine, except that the last character is a comma, and I want to drop this comma.  This is what I have tried so far:

```
r = r[:-1]
del r[-1]
```

In both cases, the list is completely deleted, not just the last character.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Well, everything except for the very last character, as I stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `rstrip`, which leaves the string alone if the last character is not a comma. Start with `r[0]` to extract the single string in the list returned by `findall`:

```
r = r[0].rstrip(',')
```

or more generally apply `rstrip` to *each* string in the list.

```
r = [x.rstrip(',') for x in r]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your list contains one element, which is the giant string

If you do want it like one giant string, you can do `r=[r[0][:-1]]`, which will remove the comma, but keep the rest of the long string.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I got it working.  Appreciate the help with this one!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
[r[0][:-1]]
```

Keep it simple! :)